Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getGeometry')
I've started playing around with OpenLayers, and the first thing I tried was to do one of the out-of-the-box tutorial exercises from the open library. I chose this one: https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/center.html and somehow it's not working out of the box, and I'm unable to determine why exactly.
I copy-pasted the three files, and I am getting the following error: main.js:56 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getGeometry') at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (main.js:56:31) at every occurrence of getGeometry.
I am confused, because I can click into getGeometry so the import seems to be working. Is there something wrong with my GeoJSON maybe?
I tried importing Geometry.js separately but that didn't work; and I also tried the simple accessible map example and that was working, so perhaps something is wrong with my imports or the way data is handled.

There are more than 3 files to copy. The import statements at the beginning of main.js import from 5 files.

The error implies that source.getFeatures() is returning an empty array. So you need to investigate why that's happening.

Why did you think this was a problem with getGeometry? The error says that feature is undefined, and that comes from const feature = source.getFeatures()[0];

I thought it was with getGeometry because that is what the error says. That is also where the red squiggly line appears when I inspect in the browser. The source could be empty, I will look into it.

The error says "of undefined". When you write source.getGeometry you're getting the getGeometry property of source.

My bad! so then the GeoJSON is the issue.

yes, I was able to solve this issue by adding the GeoJSON to a data/ folder at the top level. Thanks for the help.

If you've solved the issue you are allowed to post an answer to your own question for anyone encountering similar problems in future

I was able to solve this issue by adding the GeoJSON to a data/ folder at the top level.
